# iPhone4, how to stop an application being suspended?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am trying to test an application that needs to run over an extended period of time and to aid initial testing I am trying to find a way to stop iOS moving the application to the background and suspending it. Ultimately I will add code to facilitate the use of multi-tasking but right now I just want to better test the core mechanics without iOS pushing it into the background all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you, the user, don't stop this app, launch another app, or lock the device:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];
```

might keep your app running in the foreground.  Don't forget to re-enable the idle timer, or this could keep the device running until the battery is dead.

Answer (score 5):

You **can not** prevent ios from suspending an app. The home button will close/resign active the application and even if you request for a background task apple can kill your app at any time as it sees necessary (More than likely for memory reasons).

Comment: An exception to this rule is a jailbroken phone with backgrounder. That may be the best unofficial way to to achieve close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Much appreciated, I can get by with tweaking the screen from time to time, I was just curious if there was someway that I could force the application to stay active.